# Having issues defining Xpath while using Page object in Selenium WebDriver testing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Selenium newbie here... I am trying to create my first test framework .

Test Website : https://www.phptravels.net/

Test Case :

1. Open Browser and enter the webpage
2. Once the page is loaded , click on MyAccount ->Login

I have used xpath in my page object class and the script will run only till launching the webpage. It fails to click on the Login link .

I have tried to include an implicit wait assuming that the time taken for the page to load is longer than usual . Even then the issue persists.

Can you please help me understand what would be the correct xpath that this will work ?

Code :

POM_HomePage.java

```
package PageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class POM_HomePage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public POM_HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }



    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='li_myaccount']/ul/li[1]/a")
    WebElement LinkMyAccount;
    public WebElement clickMyAccount() {
        return LinkMyAccount;
    }


}
```

HomePage.java

```
package TestGroupID;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import PageObjects.POM_HomePage;
import Resources.MasterScript;


public class HomePage extends MasterScript{

    @Test
    public void SignIn() throws IOException {
        driver=LoadBrowser();
        LoadPropFile();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("test_website"));
        POM_HomePage pomHome=new POM_HomePage(driver);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (pomHome.clickMyAccount().isDisplayed()) {
            pomHome.clickMyAccount().click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question you have mentioned *Once the page is loaded* **click on MyAccount ->Login**. So you should have invoked `click()` method on two separate *WebElements*. But your `POM_HomePage.java` returns only **one** *WebElement* as `@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='li_myaccount']/ul/li[1]/a")`

### Solution

- In `POM_HomePage.java` define two *WebElements* and two associated `functions()` as follows :

  - MyAccount Link

    ```
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='navbar']//li[@id='li_myaccount']/a")
    WebElement LinkMyAccount;
    public WebElement clickMyAccount() {
        return LinkMyAccount;
    }
    ```
  - Login Link

    ```
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='navbar']//li[@id='li_myaccount']//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a[contains(.,'Login')]")
    WebElement LinkLogin;
    public WebElement clickLogin() {
        return LinkLogin;
    }
    ```
- In `HomePage.java` call `isDisplayed()` and `click()` for both the *WebElements* as follows :

  ```
  @Test
  public void SignIn() throws IOException {
      driver=LoadBrowser();
      LoadPropFile();
      driver.get(prop.getProperty("test_website"));
      POM_HomePage pomHome=new POM_HomePage(driver);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      if (pomHome.clickMyAccount().isDisplayed()) {
              pomHome.clickMyAccount().click();
      }
      if (pomHome.clickLogin().isDisplayed()) {
          pomHome.clickLogin().click();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, the website seems to be having issues ( "our system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php" ) and have not been able to test it yet.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks again for your help.